# UICollectionViewFlowLayout with multiple columns and dynamic cell sizing

Tags: swift

My goal is to implement a collection that looks like so:
[Instagram's discover tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXZzn.jpg)

I can achieve a similar result using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` but I am constrained to iOS versions lower than 13.0, which makes this a no go.

I have been testing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and I can achieve multiple columns using `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`, but I can't find a way to dynamically calculate the height of the cells, which can be either an image, a label, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` which will provide you an opportunity to all the modifications to cell frames and more.

```
import UIKit

class InstagramCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        
        // These attributes have all the information about how 
        // collectionView's default layout will layout your cells
        guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else { return nil }
        
        guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return nil }
        
        var newAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
        
        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout
        
        for attribute in attributes {
            if let cellAttribute = layout.layoutAttributesForItem(at: attribute.indexPath) {
                // Decide which indexPaths' cells should appear bigger
                if attribute.indexPath.item % 2 == 0 {
                    // whatever modifications you want for big cells
                    cellAttribute.frame.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
                }
                else {
                    // whatever modifications you want for small cells
                    cellAttribute.frame.size = CGSize(width: 70, height: 70)
                }
                
                // Since you are modifying default layout and making some cells bigger
                // You will need to accoun for extra height in your calculations
                // I am not doing that here

                newAttributes.append(cellAttribute)
            }
        }
        
        return newAttributes
    }
}
```

##### Usage

```
let igFlowLayout = InstagramCollectionViewFlowLayout()
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = igFlowLayout
```

##### Notes

This is just an idea of how you are supposed to create a subclass to customize cell frames. You will need to add a lot more to this according to your own implementation.

Subclassing `UICollectionViewLayout` also means that now you are fully responsible for telling `collectionView` how big it's [`collectionViewContentSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617796-collectionviewcontentsize) should be for all your data.

##### Reference

[Customizing Collection View Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/layouts/customizing_collection_view_layouts) has all the information you need to get started on this. They explain how to achieve a similar layout in their example.
[image]